# How to delete a specific fragment from back stack in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, fragment-backstack

I have a problem about removing a specific fragment from back stack.My scenario is like this.Fragment-1 is replaced with Fragment-2 and then Fragment-2 is replaced with Fragment-3.

Calling order; Fragment-1-->Fragment-2-->Fragment-3.

When Fragment-3 is on the screen and then back button is clicked, i want to go

Fragment-1.That means i want to delete Fragment-2 from back stack.

How to do this ?

Comment: you can easily switch rather than deleting Fragment .....

Answer (score 28):

In the backstack you don't have `Fragment`s, but `FragmentTransaction`s. When you `popBackStack()` the transaction is applied again, but backward. This means that (assuming you `addToBackStackTrace(null)` every time) in your backstack you have

```
1->2
2->3
```

If you don't add the second transaction to the backstack the result is that your backstack is just

```
1->2
```

and so pressing the back button will cause the execution of `2->1`, which leads to an error due to the fragment 2 not being there (you are on fragment 3).
The easiest solution is to pop the backstack before going from 2 to 3

```
//from fragment-2:
getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
   .replace(R.id.container, fragment3)
   .addToBackStack(null)
   .commit();
```

What I'm doing here is these: from fragment 2 I go back to fragment 1 and then straight to fragment 3. This way the back button will bring me again from 3 to 1.

Comment: it is not the exact solution i want.I must add fragment-2 to the back stack  when going to fragment-3.In the fragment-3 depending on a condition i want to remove fragment-2 from backstack without any action then back button is clicked,just want to go fragment-1

Comment: @sahin Ok, then it's not a viable option... Maybe you could try with [popBackStack (int id, int flags)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack%28int,%20int%29), but I did not try it, I don't know about the behaviour with animations...

Comment: When you poping backstack before going from 2 to 3 system trying to show fragment 1. Each time when you poping fragment number N it tries to show fragment number (N-1). And if you forcing to go to fragment 3 you'll get NPE during onCreateView of 1 fragment...

Comment: @llario , thanks for your answer that save my issue.

Comment: The app is crashing when using this method when using androidx appcompat library. An exception is thrown 

"Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException
Restarter must be created only during owner's initialization stage"

because the current state of the lifecycle is not Initialized. Check class SavedStateRegistryController and search for this error.

Comment: @sunlover3 I used this method on Lollipop, many things might have changed in four and a half years... There is at least one question about the problem, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56539251/backstack-management-restarter-must-be-created-only-during-owners-initializat
I'm not in andorid development anymore, can't help you much more, sorry

Comment: @Ilario Don't worry. And yes, Android developed a lot in the last years. My answer just explained the current behaviour. Thanks! Good luck in your career! :)

Answer (score 10):

I had a very similar scenario to yours, my solution was just checking the amount of backStack transactions that I had.

If the transactions where more than 0 then I would simply pop it right away
 so it would skip it when pressing back.

```
if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
}
...
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_fragment, newFrag, MAIN_FRAGMENT_TAG);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

This would successfully:

- A -> B (back pressed) -> back to A
- A -> B -> C (back pressed) -> back to A

The only downside that I see is that there is a quick flash where fragment A is displayed before going to fragment C.

Comment: Calling just `.popStack()` as others suggested - in my situation - caused the view to automatically revert to A after it went to C *- before back button was pressed*.   The `popBackStackImmediate()` listed here is what made the difference in my case, and I now have back button from C going back to A - none of the other answers I ran across had mentioned it.  Thanks!

Comment: Please specify where to write this code? I mean which fragment.

Answer (score 6):

If you are adding/launching all three fragments in the same activity, instead of the `add()`, use `replace()` (replace `Fragment2` with `Fragment3`). The `replace` method removes the current fragment from backstack before adding the new one. If you are launching `Fragment3` from a different activity, and thus you can't use `replace()`, remove `Fragment2` from backstack before starting the new activity (which adds `Fragment3`):

```
// in Fragment2, before adding Fragment3:
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
               .remove(this) // "this" refers to current instance of Fragment2
               .commit();
fragmentManager.popBackStack();
// now go ahead and launch (add) fragment3
// if fragment3 is launched from a different activity, 
// start that activity instead
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
               .add(R.id.a_container_view_in_activity, new Fragment3(),
                    Fargment3.FRAGMENT3_ID)
               .commit();
```

Answer (score 4):

Code for **Fragment A** -> **Fragment B**:

**Add** Fragment **A** in **BackStack** of Fragments

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout_container, new fragmentB());
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Code for **Fragment B** -> **Fragment C**:

**Do not Add** Fragment **B** in **BackStack** of Fragments

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout_container, new fragmentC());
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

It will works in this way: **A -> B -> C** and while **returning** **C-> A** as you excepted.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Can't use it if you want B->A again

Answer (score 3):

```
   for (int i = 0; i < mFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount(); i++) {
        currentFragment = mFragmentManager.getFragments().get(i);
        if (!(currentFragment instanceof ParticularFragment))
            mFragmentManager.popBackStack();
        else
            break;
    }
```